# Set Null Variable in SOAP UI

Tags: xml, null, wsdl, soapui

How to set `null` from this script:

```
<dat:customerNo></dat:customerNo>
```

I already tried to do this:

```
<dat:customerNo xsi:nil="true" />
```

But got error:

```
<soapenv:Fault>
<faultcode>soapenv:Server.generalException</faultcode>
<faultstring>WSDoAllReceiver: cannot convert into document; nested exception is: 
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The prefix "xsi" for attribute "xsi:nil" associated with an element type "dat:customerNo" is not bound.</faultstring>
```

Please anyone can help? Thank You!

Comment: Where do you need it in SoapUI? Groovy step? Rest  ? Soap request?

Comment: i'm not sure, it's soap request maybe. How can i check it ?

Comment: Anyone can help please ?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the definition of the xsi element in your field or in your soap envelope.

```
 <dat:customerNo xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  />
```

Comment: You're welcome, You can accept the answer if it is ok for you :)